# Origin of the energy distribution of synchrotron radiation

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays, accelerator-physics, synchrotron-radiation

Is there an easy explanation why synchrotron radiation from a bending magnet (e.g. in an electron storage ring) has an energy distribution? In other words, given a specific magnet with a defined magnetic field and electrons with a specific kinetic energy, why is the produced synchrotron radiation not monochromatic?

[image: Synchrotron radiation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a relativistic effect! For non-relativistic [cyclotron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron_radiation), the spectrum is mostly monochromatic at the gyro-frequency and the angular distribution is basically over all angles. But for highly relativistic [synchrotron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation), the radiation from the electrons is strongly “beamed”, like a headlight, in a very narrow cone ahead of the electron. This means that the power received by a distant observer is a sharp spike in time, once per revolution. The Fourier transform of this sharp spike contains a broad distribution of frequencies.

The graphs on page 52 of [this PDF](http://www.tat.physik.uni-tuebingen.de/~kokkotas/Teaching/Field_Theory_files/FT_course05.pdf) show the transition from the monochromatic non-relativistic case to the broad-spectrum highly-relativistic case. Note that these graphs have linear rather than logarithmic axes, so the final one doesn’t look like the one you showed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and thanks for the "classical" example of the cyclotron. That made sense for me. However, I don't understand the Fourier argument. Is this equivalent to the time-energy uncertainty principle?

Comment: If you want to create a waveform that is a sharp spike in time, you have to superpose sine waves with lots of different frequencies so that they cancel each other out everywhere except where the spike is. This mathematical fact is related to the time-energy uncertainty principle, since energy is proportional to frequency. A signal localized in time cannot also be localized in frequency.

Comment: As https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle explains: “Generally speaking, the more concentrated f (x) is, the more spread out its Fourier transform f̂ (ξ) must be. In particular, the scaling property of the Fourier transform may be seen as saying: if we squeeze a function in x, its Fourier transform stretches out in ξ. It is not possible to arbitrarily concentrate both a function and its Fourier transform.”

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting and marking it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I accepted, can't upvote yet :-)